# how to move a hash key where condition into class method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a query to search a certain category of users (lawyers) by their name in my Rails app (which uses a Postgres db) like this

```
 @users = User.where(:lawyer => 'true').text_search(params[:query])
```

This is the method on the User.rb class

```
def self.text_search(query)
  if query.present?
    where("name @@ :q", q: query)
  else
    scoped
  end
end
```

Instead of using `where.(:lawyer => 'true')` in the controller, I wanted to (even though it doesn't affect the query) put that condition inside the method on User.rb class like this

```
 @users = User.text_search(params[:query])

def self.text_search(query)
  if query.present?
    where("name @@ :q", q: query, :lawyer => 'true')
  else
    scoped
  end
end
```

However, now the search doesn't work (or rather it just searches by the name query)

How would I add that lawyer == true condition at the in the text_search method.

Comment: I have since moved onto `squeel` gem as an improvement on AR query builder, but what about `where(first_condition).where(second_condition)`. I suspect you'd have to do this because of your argument list. `:lawyer => true` is arbitrary, whereas `q: query` is not.

Comment: Actually that `where("name @@ :q", q: query).where(:lawyer => 'true')` works if you want to write an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use a scope:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :lawyers, :conditions => { :is_lawyer => true }
end
```

Then in the controller:

```
 @users = User.lawyers.text_search(params[:query])
```

You could go all out and define a class method on the user model:

```
def self.lawyers_named(name)
  lawyers.text_search(name)
end
```

Then call it with:

```
@users = User.lawyers_named(params[:query])
```

Comment: Thanks. Would you do it that way just for the purpose of organizing the code or is there a performance gain you'd expect to see?